# How to generate request token 'manually' in identityserver4

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

[auth flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLNvG.png)

We want to implement an oauth authentication flow. In the image to the link is the flow we want to implement for authenticating our users. Let's center in the AuthServer component which holds an instance of identity server 4 configured to use hybrid flow. When BGServer (just a server) sends the request for getting a request token,

A.how do I create this request token (to be used later to exchange it for an access token)?

B.Is actually possible to fit the oauth process in what we want to implement or it's just stupid to use it?

note that LDAP component can also be AzureAD or a custom login manager.

I'm actually quite lost in all the process and maybe I don't ask the question properly, sorry for that.
Thanks

Comment: So your BGServer is say an API server? Why do you want the BG server to have a token if you already have a client? BGServer should only be validating the token against your AuthServer. Your authserver should manage authentication (including integratoin with any 3rd parties). Your BGServer should only use AuthServer to verify token and token should be passed by the client (browser/mobile)

Comment: thanks for the comment! Yes, BGServer can be seen as an API server. I understand what you say, but the reason why BGServer is doing the request for a authorization code/request token is because they first want to use their own authentication with 'UserAuthKey'. Personally I don't see the point neither and I agree it should only be validating the tokens. 

In any case, how could I customize IdentityServer4 classes or which configuration should I use to achieve the flow defined?

Comment: That approach breaks the security audit chain, which means you are vulnerable to hackers leveraging it as entry point. Other than that, you can leverage the resource owner password. No simple way to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal is pretty much anti-OAuth in that is involves passing credentials via the client app. You should push any custom authentication logic to your AuthServer and make the client the mobile app then have it do an implicit/hybrid authorize request to ADFS/AzureAD or whatever.

So for example:

1. User is directed to AuthServer authorize endpoint in their default browser
2. User presented with UI to prompt for UserAuthKey
3. AuthServer does whatever validation and checks it needs to
4. AuthServer uses OIDC to authenticate with LDAP provider (e.g. via AD FS or Azure AD)
5. Session is established on the AuthServer
6. Client receives response containing tokens (or token+code if hybrid)
7. Client calls BGServer using the obtained access token

For further reading on why the above is good and the original proposal is bad check out Scott Brady's excellent article here:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mackie, I will check the specs again considering you input. It is helpful.